AutoMapping in Java: nested recursive objects
I need to do a model -> DTO mapping. The model structure leads to recursion during mapping. Let's take an example to make it easier to understand.
public class Father {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Child> children;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}

public class Child {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Father father;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}

public class FatherDto {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<ChildDto> children;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}

public class ChildDto {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private FatherDto father;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}

Mapping the following models would lead to circular recursion.
I know that by using mapper like MapStruct I could write methods like this to avoid circular recursion:
@Mapping(target = "father", ignore = true)
    ChildDto childToChildDto(Child child);

But I was wondering, is there a way to automatically recognize a recursion without having to apply custom annotation for each model like in my example?

Does this answer your question? MapStruct issue while recursive mapping

No. In this question they used a methodology that I also attached, but it's not what I need, unfortunately.

You did not mention what are you using for mapping, are you using mapstruct or other library ?

I tried using MapStruct and didn't find a solution. I evaluate any other type of library that can satisfy my request.
